# Conversão de Data ("yyyy/mm/dd") para ("dd/mm/yyyy")

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

Eu estou usando um campo do tipo `Date` no arquivo `HTML`, para facilitar a seleção da data, porém ela vai salva para o banco em formato americano `yyyy/mm/dd`, 
fiz a seguinte `query` para transformar esses dados e mostrar de forma `dd/mm/yyyy` , mas não funcionou:

```
$seleciona= mysqli_query($conexao,"
    SELECT TO_Char(r.Data,'dd/mm/yyyy'),r.CodReuniao Datas
    FROM reuniao r
    group by TO_Char(r.Data,'dd/mm/yyyy')
    order by Datas ASC"
);
```

Tem algum erro de sintaxe?

Comment: Tem erro de sintaxe sim. `TO_CHAR` é Oracle (e talvez algum outro SGBD). MySQL não funciona assim. Talvez o `DATE_FORMAT` te interesse

Comment: voce sabe alguma possível solução?

Comment: Veja os links do quadro amarelo acima, e a função DATE_FORMAT no manual do MySQL

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format